# Sphinx how to exclude column from search?

Tags: sphinx

Is there any way to exclude column from Sphinx search?

I have index with columns id and many others.
When i want to search only by id - "@id 8500", but when i want search everything except id - how to do that? 
I don't want to list all others columns like "@(col1,col2,...,coln)"

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
It is "$!(id) 8500"